# Extending QString to overload construction

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to extend the QString class from Qt to provide some convenience for converting to/from various string types.

For example, I would like to be able to write lines like:

```
MyStringClass myString(_T("Hello World!"));
```

and get a MyStringClass object that behaves just like a QString. Using just QString, that would have had to be written like:

```
QString myString = QString::fromWCharArray(_T("Hello World!"));
```

There's other functionality I would like to add to MyStringClass, but I'm getting hung up on how overload the constructor to accept a wchar_t parameter as in my example. It appears QString's internal data is private, so my derived class can't directly set up the object as necessary (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Is it really that bad to write `QString myString = QString::fromWCharArray(_T("Hello World!"));
`? It's more explicit than the constructor you want to create, and you'd have standard code understandable by everyone.

Comment: I didn't want to muck up the question itself, but in case anyone is wondering the justification for this... I'm working on a fairly large project that is currently all C++/MFC. Mandate is now that new code must be written using C++/Qt, but all our existing functions that take strings expect handfuls of different string types, including CString/wchar_t/_bstr_t/LPCTSTR/etc. Eventually those will be ported, so I would like to have a class that abstracts the conversion details so we don't have to update those conversions to/from QString once we start moving old string types to QString.

Comment: @Laurent see my comment above ^

Comment: Without the QT code in front of me -- does QString have a virtual destructor?  If not, it is likely an indication that the original writers of the library did not intend for you to derive from it, at least not pubically.  That means you're left to private (or protected) inheritance or containment and you are then free to wrap that object and provide the necessary public member functions in your wrapper interface.

Comment: @Chad That's the impression I was getting after I started giving this a shot. The destructor is inline ~QString() and there are plenty of other subtleties that suggest QString isn't friendly to extend. I was hoping I could avoid a public wrapper to a QString data member, which is why I asked the question. Hopefully someone has a creative answer, or else your suggestion will be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really aren't *abstracting* anything there, it's a bad idea.  If you bite the bullet and fix it now you won't ever have to deal with it again.  If you keep deferring it, the cost will increase as you go.

You really want to keep your basic types as simple as possible.

Having 6 different string types is not manageable either, so narrow it down to QString as soon as possible.  If you want help converting the types, write some adapter functions.  I've used simple things like the below when converting between QString and std::string for convenience.

```
std::string sstr(const QString &str);

QString qstr(const std::string &str);
```

I'm sure you can write similar for the other types you mentioned.

If you really want to write your own class to help with the transition, then you should protect yourself from its continued use.  The real risk is that despite its intended deprecation, it is used forever.  If you allow your new string class in public interfaces, it will be hard to get rid of.   At that point its just another string type to handle with the others.

```
class MyStringClass {
public:
  MyStringClass(const std::string &val);
  MyStringClass(const char *val);
  MyStringClass(const wchar_t *val);

  QString getQString() const;
};
```

This gives an easy way to get what you need in the new code, and doesn't allow implicit conversions.  QString is a value object anyway, not sure you could use it the way you want to.

Chances are you won't convert most of the code, but as long as its in private implementation it won't hurt you that often.

Comment: I was looking to extend, not abstract. The project's code base is nearly 2 million lines of code and heavily relies on MFC. Getting everything to QString/Qt isn't going to happen overnight, and we have aggressive milestones for new functionality as is. To avoid continuing the pain of multiple string types, I was hoping to shoehorn this class in as a universal adapter between old and new. This way it's less painful when we start converting legacy code in chunks as we have time. We have a collection of utility functions that do conversions now, but it generally leads to messier code.

Comment: @bkuhns Having multiple string types is tedious and messy, regardless of whether its legacy code or not.  Your utility functions aren't messy, your problem is messy.  If you want to introduce kludge as a stop-gap measure, then it will work for the short term.  The hard part is when people continue using it for a decade afterwards.

Comment: @bkuns Updated answer with another option for transition.  It takes discipline to get everyone to not use such things in public interfaces, so buyer beware. :)

Comment: I realize now with your updated solution why you don't agree with this idea. I never intended for this class to be used in public interfaces, but that's exactly what this would allow. I missed that, thanks. If old code (holding a wchar_t, perhaps) needs to call a new function expecting a QString, then that's a sign the old code needs some updates to fit the new call types. Making a class to abstract that would certainly encourage kludge. Thanks for pointing that out! What I really need is a class of static funcs that'll convert *from* QString so it's easy to call legacy functions.